# JPA/Hibernate - Is it safe to change the connection whilst serving a request?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am currently using JPA2/Hibernate 5 in my project. I have enabled multi-schema support. Within my web-application every time a new user is created, a schema is created just for that user by:

```
 connection.createStatement().execute("CREATE SCHEMA " + tenantIdentifier + "");
        connection.createStatement().execute("USE " + tenantIdentifier + "");
        SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(
                (MetadataImplementor) metadataSources.buildMetadata(),
                connection);
        export.create(true, true);
```

If 2 web requests were made at the same time, one which created this new schema and another that tried to fetch data from a different schema, would  a data access issue happen or is the connection object that the session using created per request? All DB interactions are handled by spring's jpa repositories. Moreover I am using spring boot

Comment: Normally two web request implies two separate transactions.  Each transactions will have its own Hibernate Session, and hence separate Connection.   You shouldn't encounter case of same connection serving two web requests

Comment: @AdrianShum thanks!